# Get input for a while statement

Tags: python

```
while int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates): ")) != 0:
    #do stuff to the input
```

How would I store the input for the line the user entered in the line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be best to make your while-loop something like this:

```
# loop continuously
while True:
    # get the input and store it in the variable inp
    inp = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates): "))
    # break the loop if inp equals 0
    if inp == 0:
        break
    # do stuff to the input
```

Comment: Alright, that's what I currently have, was just trying to optimize it, so If that's already the best. I will keep that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best and cleaner solution is to make an infinite loop and break it when the user input 0:

```
while True:
    inp = int(input("Input an integer (0 terminates): "))
    if inp == 0:
        break 
    print inp
```

Comment: The (now removed) first one will print `inp` (or whatever it does in the loop) once more after `0` has been inputted.

Comment: Mmmh indeed! Good eye... I remove it then. The `while True` is the best solution I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
while 1:
    n = input("Input an integer (0 terminates): ")
    if n == 0:
        break
    # do something with n
```